# Combining two reactions in equilibrium with same reactants but different products: What would be the new K?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, kinetics

If I have the reactions :

> A<sub>(g)</sub> ⇌ B<sub>(g)</sub>     K<sub>1</sub> 
> A<sub>(g)</sub> ⇌ C<sub>(g)</sub>     K<sub>2</sub>

Am I able to add the equations like done in Hess's law despite nothing canceling out? And if I can do so, is the new equilibrium constant equal to K<sub>1</sub>$\cdot$K<sub>2</sub>?

In other words, is the following equation true?

> 2A<sub>(g)</sub> ⇌ B<sub>(g)</sub> + C<sub>(g)</sub>     K = K<sub>1</sub>$\cdot$K<sub>2</sub>

Using the law of mass action, this seems valid as K would equal $\mathrm{[B][C]/[A]^2}$ which can be rewritten as $\mathrm{[B]/[A] \cdot [C]/[A]}$ which equals K<sub>1</sub>$\cdot$K<sub>2</sub>; however, this implies that the concentration of B is always equal to that of C (assuming the initial concentration of both were equal) which seems unreasonable.

Comment: There is no new K - that's two different reactions.

Comment: You can calculate a K to get from B to C.

Comment: Or build an enzyme that couples the two reactions in a 1:1 stoichiometry.

Comment: @Mithoron But can´t two different reactions be added to produce a new K? Like as  Karsten Theis said the two reactions can be subtracted to get B<-->C with K = K2/K1, so how come the two reactions in the question can not be added?

Comment: If 1 A forms  B or C it does not mean 2 A react together forming both. If it would, then initially pure A would lead to B:C ratio 1:1 , what is not the case unless accidentally both original constants are the same

Comment: Do you have real example one reactant producing two different products under the same conditions as showed in your first two equations? I don't think it is real. $K$ is only depending on temperature so two reactions have to be in two different temperatures, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in saying that the law of mass action applies in this case. The two equations (1 and 2 respectively)

$$\ce{A(g) <=>[K_\mathrm{1}] B(g)}$$
$$\ce{A(g) <=>[K_\mathrm{2}] C(g)}$$

can be combined to form an equation with $K_\mathrm{eq}$ = $K_\mathrm{1}K_\mathrm{2}$:

$$\ce{2A(g) <=>[K_\mathrm{1}K_\mathrm{2}] B(g) +C(g)}$$

However, do be wary that just because the the right side of the equation has both products B and C with the same stochiometric coefficients, this does **not** mean that at equilibrium, the two will have the same concentration. Why? The "reactants" - the two molecules of A - *don't actually react with each other*. Instead, each molecule of A can independently be converted into either B or C - if $K_\mathrm{1}$ is larger than $K_\mathrm{2}$, the chances that B will be the produced molecule is higher.

To mathematically illustrate this, write out the equilibrium expressions for reactions 1 and 2, and solve for the concentration of A:

$$ \ce{K_\mathrm{1} = \frac{[B]}{[A]} -> [A] = \frac{[B]}{K_\mathrm{1}}} $$
$$ \ce{K_\mathrm{2} = \frac{[C]}{[A]} -> [A] = \frac{[C]}{K_\mathrm{2}}} $$

Set the two equations for [A] equal to each other to obtain:

$$ \ce{[A] = \frac{[B]}{K_\mathrm{1}} = \frac{[C]}{K_\mathrm{2}} ->$$
$$\ce {\frac{[B]}{[C]} = \frac{K_\mathrm{1}}{K_\mathrm{2}}}} $$

Thus, we can see that the ratio of the concentrations of B and C is the ratio of their respective equilibrium constants of formation from A.

I believe the problem you have here is that you are confusing elementary steps with the overall equation. Reactions 1 and 2 are elementary steps, but the overall reaction is not. Thus, you have to be much more careful and ask yourself the following question: *are the reactants actually reacting together, or are the two reactions completely independent of each other*? A good way to intuitively see this would be to consider the following equilibria:

$$\ce{A(g) <=>[K_\mathrm{3}] B(g)}$$
$$\ce{C(g) <=>[K_\mathrm{4}] D(g)}$$

Combining these, we obtain:

$$\ce{A(g) + C(g) <=>[K_\mathrm{3}K_\mathrm{4}] B(g) +D(g)}$$

I hope you can see that although B and D have the same stochiometric coefficients, the amount of each at equilibrium will be different as reactions 3 and 4 are completely independent of each other. In fact, the above equation isn't even really a reaction, as the two reactants do not react with each other. Rather, it serves more of a general observational purpose, such as, I put "A" and "C" into a container and they produce "B" and D". They could be reacting with each other (if they were, it would be an elementary step, and [B] = [D]), or they could just be in independent equilibriums. The above equation cannot be used to find the relative amounts of B or D; you must break down the reaction into the elementary steps to discover that, just as with the equation you derived.

For those that would like a concrete example of a reaction where "A" can turn into several different products without reacting with other molecules of "A", one that comes to mind from experience is the [isomerization of β-pinene](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165237007000095) at temperatures above 773 K:

$$\ce{β-pinene <=>[K_\mathrm{x}] p-menthadiene}$$
$$\ce{β-pinene <=>[K_\mathrm{y}] limonene}$$
$$\ce{β-pinene <=>[K_\mathrm{z}] myrcene}$$

I've left out the organic structures/mechanisms here for sake of simplicity. There are three products formed instead of two, but the point remains the same. Reactions where one molecule isomerizes to several different products at high temperatures with competing mechanisms are quite common in industrial chemistry. Similar to reactions 1 and 2, the ratios of products in the isomerization of β-pinene will be the ratios of the equilibrium constants. Something interesting to note is that since these equilibrium constants change with temperature, higher or lower temperatures will favor certain isomerization products (see [van't Hoff equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_equation)), although having just one produced is notoriously difficult.

Another more common example of a reaction where $\ce{2A(g) -> B(g) +C(g)}$ would be that of a nuclide that emits radiation through both alpha and beta decay, such as <sup>212</sup>Bi. In many of these cases, the rates of alpha and beta radiation of nuclide A are different, indicating that decay products B and C will be different as well. However, because radioactive decay is not an equilibrium, its applicability is limited in this case, and rate constants of decay are used instead of equilibrium constants.